# How do I execute my functions as background processes in Node.js with Bull?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, worker

I have a Node.js web application in which I make some 3rd party API calls with, creating some really long request/response times. This causes my Heroku to timeout ~50% of the time, and according to Heroku docs there's no way to change this hard limit. They recommend using background processes to scale, and this seemed like a good fit to the problem (they provide examples and recommend using https://optimalbits.github.io/bull/).

I'm following the simple example provided by Heroku here https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-workers-example), however for my sake this example is a bit too simple.

I have a filed named `worker.js` which will be my worker. There is a function `start()` that instantiates the queue, and tells the queue how to process jobs. My issue is that I will be adding jobs to the queue via my API endpoints, and I would like each job to execute specific functions in order to complete their task.

Here is the `start()` function:

```
function start(){
 let workQueue = new Queue('work', REDIS_URL);
  workQueue.process(maxJobsPerWorker, async (job,data) => {
    return {message: "Finished"};
  });
```

What I would like to do is to execute different functions in the logic block instead of returning a finished message. For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
function start(){
 let workQueue = new Queue('work', REDIS_URL);
  workQueue.process(maxJobsPerWorker, async (job,data) => {
    return someFunction();
  });
```

Again, that would be straight-forward enough if I needed to run the same function every time, but I will be running several different functions that use different inputs. So `someFunction` is a variable and not a constant.

I was considering passing the name of the function to execute to the job directly, something like this: 
`let job = await workQueue.add({ callback: functionName });`

However I can't really tell if this works or not... How can I get this up and running?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the start function is necessary. You can just define your functions like this `async function myFunction(){ //Logic goes here }` and then when you need that call you just execute them using `await myFunction()` or of it returns something you can put it in a variable. But the function that you want to execute needs to contain the `async` word for `await` to work.

Also return works the same way as await. So you could let's say you have a getter method you can say something like `async function findWorker(){ return database.find({ workerId }); };`.

Comment: I'm using throng for clustering, and I call the start function to begin another process. I have my business logic defined as you described, and typically I execute them within my requests - that's what i'm trying to move away from.

The issue is I'm not sure when/where to execute the function within my worker file.

Comment: Shouldn't it execute when the queue isn't empty? Because then I would say that when a call gets done it should start the execution immediately. Maybe I don't really get what you're trying to achieve tho.

Comment: Yes, the queue will execute whatever logic is within the `process` method call. The thing is within that `process` call I want to tell my queue to execute specific functions based on which API endpoint I hit. So if I make a post request to let's say "/job/user", I want my queue to know that in order to process the job that was just created, it needs to run like a `addUser()` function or something (i.e. `queue.process( () => { return addUser();});`. I'm just not sure how to get my queue to behave like that. I'm probably just explaining it poorly lol

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to do tbh lol. I don't think I can help you with your problem I'm sorry. Good luck with finding an answer to your problem though!